# type 'int' is not subtype of type 'String' on Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I modified `description` value to `1` on my database.

```
List<DataEquipmentReg> values = snapshot.data;


 assetArray.add('${values[i].eq_no.toString()} : ${values[i].description.toString()}');
```

After edit `description` value to `String`, Error is not coming

**DataEquipmentReg POJO Class**

```
class DataEquipmentReg {
 final String eq_no;
  final String description;
}
```

**Widget**

```
   Text(assetArray[index].toString(),),
```

**Database in sqlite**

```
  await db.execute("""CREATE TABLE EquipmentRegTable(eq_no STRING, description STRING)""");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem like this,

in my read data on cache method, I changed this,

```
  Future<List<DataEquipmentReg>> displayEquipmentReg() async {
    var db = await db1;
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps = await db.query('EquipmentRegTable');

    return List.generate(maps.length, (i) {
      return DataEquipmentReg(
        eq_no: '${maps[i]['eq_no']}',
        description'${ maps[i]['description']}',
      );
    });
  }
```

Comment: You should wrap that await in a try catch block https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/futures#handling-errors-async