# flutter: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String' error even if the data structure is correct for model

Tags: arrays, list, flutter, addition, provider

I have a `reward` model. which looks like below:

```
class RewardModel {

  String id, status;
  DateTime createdAt, updatedAt;

  RewardModel({
    @required this.id,
    @required this.status,
    @required this.createdAt,
    @required this.updatedAt,
  });
}
```

on the Provide side, I have the following code:

```
try {
        data['collection']['userData']['rewards'].forEach((result){
          print(result);
          _rewards.add(
            RewardModel(
              id: result['id'].toString(),
              status: status(result['status_id']),
              createdAt: DateTime.parse(result['created_at']),
              updatedAt: DateTime.parse(result['updated_at']),
            )
          ); 
        });
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }
```

I do get the data from the request made and is as followed:

```
flutter: {id: 1, user_id: 1, status_id: 4, created_at: 2019-12-23 20:54:43, updated_at: 2019-12-23 20:54:43}
flutter: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String'
```

but on the very next line, I get the error. Whats wrong with this?

also below answers are no use to me:

[flutter http post "type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58358234/flutter-http-post-type-int-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-string-in-type-cast)

[type 'int' is not subtype of type 'String' on Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56375509/type-int-is-not-subtype-of-type-string-on-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

this error happens when you parse **int** value to **String** variable

Simply change this line

**from**

```
          status: status(result['status_id']),
```

**to**

```
          status: status(result['status_id'].toString()),
```

**or** change this line

**from**

```
         String status
```

**to**

```
         int status
```